# Connect app maker server script with cloud storage bucket

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-app-maker

I am trying to connect Google App Maker with Google Cloud Storage using Cloud Storage JSON API

I'm using a service account but the response is:

"domain": "global",

"reason": "authError",

"message": "Invalid Credentials"

How I can do that?

Comment: Hi, have you find solution? I'm working on this connection too, but cannot figure out how to set the service on Google cloud console, I see [this blog](https://ctrlq.org/code/20074-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage) but don't know how to get that CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET, would you kindly share your configuration? Thanks.

Comment: The problem was resolved. The application user could not add / download files to the repository because he did not have permissions. I just had to give it the "Storage Object Manager" permission in Google Cloud Console and it was fixed. I hope it helps you.